# On the fly android search using quick search box

Tags: java, android, search

I've implemented a search in my application using The quick search box, now i want the search results to show on the fly as the user types.
Is it possible?

Comment: Look up `Supporting Search Suggestions from a Content Provider` - there is a section on this in Reto Meier's Professional Android 4 Application Development book.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting a `setOnKeyListener()` on your View.

```
view.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER))
        {
            // Perform action on key press - pop up your search box and focus on it

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```